# Will the timezone used in MySQL Date and Time functions cause conflicts/issues?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a website which allows visitors to view content, and has the option for them to register and login (which gives them permission to submit content).

- Whenever content is submitted by users I do a `INSERT INTO` query in the `content` table, I use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` to store the timestamp in the column `content_timestamp` (which is the time of when the content is submitted).
- I also allow users to optionally select a timezone (supports all timezones from `http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php`) from a dropdown menu in there usercp - and a column (`user_timezone`) in the `users` table gets `UPDATE`'d with that, so all displayed dates are adjusted to that (if selected).
- One the page which the content is displayed I display the formatted date (of when the content is submitted) - if they are not logged or have logged in and not selected a timezone (in the usercp) I format it in GMT otherwise I use there selected timezone e.g.:

---

```
<?php
if (!is_logged_in() || is_logged_in() && empty($row['user_timezone'])) {
   echo gmdate('d/m/y', $row['content_timestamp']) . ' GMT'; //in GMT
} else {
   date_default_timezone_set($row['user_timezone']);
   echo date('d/m/y', $row['content_timestamp']); //use the users timezone
} 
?>
```

---

Now everything is fine but now I'm planning on schedulling a cronjob weekly and monthly (this will be the weekly featured and monthly featured content) which will access a php file which will do a `INSERT INTO` query (of top rated content) and add it to the `featured` table - along with the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` (`featured_timestamp` - of when it was added).

The cronjob is set to access the php file the first day of every week 12 am midnight GMT and the first day of every month 12 am midnight GMT.

...Now getting to the problem:

I'm displaying the featured content by comparing timestamps using the `MySQL` Date and Time functions like so (below example will return the weekly featured content):

```
SELECT * FROM featured WHERE WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(featured_timestamp), 1) = WEEK(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 1) AND
FROM_UNIXTIME(featured_timestamp, '%Y %M') = FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '%Y %M')
```

**So will this cause any timezone conflicts/issues seeing as the cronjob is accessing the file in GMT and I'm unaware of what timezone `MySQL` `WEEK()` and `DATE_FORMAT()` use (just curious as that would mean comparison queries like the above could produce incorrect results)?**